# Definition of $ 1 + \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{\ddots}}}}$

Tags: self-learning, continued-fractions

Is there a definition of $ 1 + \frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{\ddots}}}}$? I am somewhat familiar with continued fractions; that is, I am aware that their convergence depends on whether our input is rational or not. This is not a homework problem, I am just curious about this topic which has gotten little attention in my current studies. If this expression is defined, what is it and does it converge?

Comment: What other methods do you know that could perhaps check for convergence?

Comment: In general, I am aware of methods such as the ratio test, n-th root test, and comparison test, but I am not sure how I would apply them here.

Comment: All simple continued fractions, including yours, converge.  This is an immediate corollary of Theorem 10 (p.10) in A. Ya. Khinchin *Continued Fractions*, University of Chicago Press, 1964.

Comment: It is a simple continued fraction because all the numerators are 1, right?

Comment: That, and because all the partial denominators (in this case 1, 2, 3, etc.) are positive integers.  As for the exact value, I would guess offhand that little is known about it; but it is quite easy to see that it is very nearly equal to $\frac{83120346}{57999271} \approx   1.43312742672231\ldots$, so you might try searching for 1.43312742672 and see if you find anything.

Comment: For example, [OEIS has a section about it](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C4%2C3%2C3%2C1%2C2%2C7&language=english&go=Search). To my surprise and delight, there is a closed form!

Comment: Alan Baker proved it transcendental?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A = [a_0; a_1, a_2, \ldots]$ be shorthand for the continued fraction $$a_0 + \cfrac1{a_1 + \cfrac1{a_2 + \cdots}}.$$  It is perhaps the most important theorem of continued fractions that $A$ is *always* well-defined when the $a_i$ are positive integers.  This is an immediate consequence of a more general theorem which states that $A$ converges if and only if the series $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i$$ diverges.  (See Theorem 10 (p. 10) in A. Ya. Khinchin, *Continued Fractions*, University of Chicago Press 1964.)

Since the $a_i$ in this case increase fairly quickly, the  partial quotients of the continued fraction itself converge fairly quickly, and a computer calculation of the truncated fraction $[1; 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]$ yields the approximation $$A\approx 1.43312742672231,$$ which is good to 14 decimal places.  (I used the `cf-evaluate` program [found here](https://github.com/mjdominus/cf).) Plugging the sequence of digits into [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) reveals  that this is [OEIS sequence A060997](http://oeis.org/A060997) and the claim that the value is exactly $$\frac{I_0(2)}{I_1(2)}$$ where $I_0$ and $I_1$ are [modified Bessel functions of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1).  (Unfortunately, OEIS gives neither a proof nor a reference.)

OEIS also claims (again unfortunately without proof; I suppose it follows from the Taylor series expansions for the Bessel functions) that $$A = \frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!^2}}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n!^2}}.$$

It does at least provide an email address for the author of the entry, so you could write and ask him for a reference.

[ Addendum 2016-08-20: Jack D'Aurizio explains the Bessel function thing in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1871798 .]

Comment: Sure, I did very little; mostly just copied stuff out of OEIS.

Comment: A reference for the material involving the ratio of Bessel functions and the continued fraction constant: "Transcendental Numbers" Carl Ludwig Siegel (1949) pp. 65-72