# Convergence of a Harmonic Continued Fraction

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, continued-fractions

Does this continued fraction converge?

$$\cfrac { 1 }{ 1+\cfrac { 1 }{ 2+\cfrac { 1 }{ 3+\cfrac { 1 }{ 4+\ddots  }  }  }  } $$

($[0;1,2,3,4, \dots]$)

I tried approximating a few values but I couldn't make out whether it converges or diverges. Can anyone provide a proof whether this converges or diverges. If it converges, please add what it converges to.

Comment: I like this question ;) It seems slightly related to one i asked, what have you tried so far? Anything other that approximating?

Comment: All simple continued fractions converge.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstant.html

Comment: ^ Might as well put that as the answer.

Comment: I was trying to find upper and lower bounds of the continued fraction. But the link makes it clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [modified Bessel functions of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) fulfills the recurrence relation:
$$ I_n(\alpha)=\frac{\alpha}{2n}\left(I_{n-1}(\alpha)-I_{n+1}(\alpha)\right)\tag{1}$$
due to the integral representation:
$$ I_n(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(nx)\,e^{\alpha\cos x}\,dx \tag{2}$$
and the cosine addition formulas. A straightforward consequence of $(1)$ is that:
$$ \frac{I_n(\alpha)}{I_{n-1}(\alpha)}=\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{2}{\alpha}\,n+\cfrac{1}{\cfrac{2}{\alpha}\,(n+1)+\cdots}}\tag{3} $$
hence by plugging in $\alpha=2$ and $n=1$ we get:
$$\boxed{ \cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3+\cdots}}}=\frac{I_1(2)}{I_0(2)}=\color{red}{\frac{\sum_{m\geq 0}^{\phantom{A}}\frac{1}{m!(m+1)!}}{\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{m!^2}}}\approx 0.697774657964.}\tag{4} $$
The convergence of the LHS is granted by the fact that it is an ordinary [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction), $[0;1,2,3,4,\ldots]$. Bounds are easily derived from the red ratio, since both the numerator and the denominator are very fast-converging series.

Comment: That is a nice one Jack (+1)

Comment: @tired: thank you, tired :)

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how to go from the recurrence to the continued fraction. This is pretty cool +1

Answer (score 8):

By Seidel-Stern theorem, for a continued fraction of the following form to converge:

$$\cfrac { 1 }{ a_1+\cfrac { 1 }{ a_2+\cfrac { 1 }{ a_3+\cfrac { 1 }{ a_4+\dots  }  }  }  }$$

$$a_k >0$$

The following sum has to diverge:

$$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+\cdots$$

Thus, even the following continued fraction converges:

$$\cfrac { 1 }{ 1+\cfrac { 1 }{1/2+\cfrac { 1 }{ 1/3+\cfrac { 1 }{1/4+\dots  }  }  }  }=\frac{\pi}{2}-1$$

But this one diverges:

$$\cfrac { 1 }{ 1+\cfrac { 1 }{1/2^2+\cfrac { 1 }{ 1/3^2+\cfrac { 1 }{1/4^2+\dots  }  }  }  }$$

Comment: How did you know that for the continued fraction to diverge, $ a_1 +a_2 + a_3 + \cdots $ must diverge?

Comment: @GohP.iHan, Seidel-Stern theorem, see for example http://math.stackexchange.com/q/556114/269624 P.S. You meant to say for the continued fraction to **converge**, right?

Comment: @You'erInMyEye: Oh right. I miswrote that. Thanks for the link, but unfortunately, the link in that top solution is now dead.

Comment: How do you proof the continued fraction for pi/2-1? I have been looking for a proof but I can't find it and I don't see it myself either

Comment: @DanielD., I don't remember the details, but I believe we could transform it formally into a series and then prove that the series converges to this value. You could probably google "continued fractions for pi"

Comment: I did before exactly the term you suggest and a whole lot of variations to no avail but will keep trying, if you remember it please let me know, thank you very much.

Comment: @DanielD., of course, don't mention it. If it helps, I checked this numerically in Mathematica (due to slow convergence I had to use a lot of terms, but the value seems correct)

Comment: that is nice, as it appears on wikipedia I just mindlessly
assumed it was true but I should have verified it too, besides google I used approach0.xyz and found two mentions on MSE but no proof, I think I will have to post a question but as this contains the reciprocal of the naturals and because of the harmonics series and all that it looks weird to me that a proof of this doesn't pop up everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

This particular one is $I_1(2)/I_0(2)$ where $I_0$ and $I_1$ are modified Bessel functions of the first kind, of orders $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Hm... this answer feels... empty.

Answer (score 2):

Jack's answer is perfect but just in case you're as dumb as I am,  here are the steps connecting the recurrence to the actual continued fraction:

$$ I_n(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha}{2n} \left( I_{n-1}(\alpha)  - I_{n+1}(\alpha) \right)  $$

$$ \frac{I_n(\alpha)}{I_{n-1}(\alpha)} = \frac{\alpha}{2n} \left( 1  - \frac{I_{n+1}(\alpha)}{I_{n-1}(\alpha)} \right)  $$
$$ \frac{I_n(\alpha)}{I_{n-1}(\alpha)} = \frac{\alpha}{2n} \left( 1  - \frac{I_{n}(\alpha)}{I_{n}(\alpha)} \frac{I_{n+1}(\alpha)}{I_{n-1}(\alpha)} \right)  $$

$$ \frac{I_n(\alpha)}{I_{n-1}(\alpha)} = \frac{\alpha}{2n} \left( 1  - \frac{I_{n}(\alpha)}{I_{n-1}(\alpha)} \frac{I_{n+1}(\alpha)}{I_{n}(\alpha)} \right)  $$

Now we solve for $\frac{I_{n}}{I_{n-1}}$

$$ \left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{2n} \frac{I_{n+1}(\alpha)}{I_n(\alpha)} \right) \frac{I_n(\alpha)}{I_{n-1}(\alpha)} = \frac{\alpha}{2n} $$

$$  \frac{I_n(\alpha)}{I_{n-1}(\alpha)} = \frac{\frac{\alpha}{2n}}{\left(1 + \frac{\alpha}{2n} \frac{I_{n+1}(\alpha)}{I_n(\alpha)} \right)} $$

$$  \frac{I_n(\alpha)}{I_{n-1}(\alpha)} = \frac{\frac{2n}{\alpha}}{\frac{2n}{\alpha}} \frac{\frac{\alpha}{2n}}{\left(1 +  \frac{\alpha}{2n} \frac{I_{n+1}(\alpha)}{I_n(\alpha)} \right)} = \frac{1}{\frac{2n }{\alpha} + \frac{I_{n+1}(\alpha)}{I_n(\alpha)}} $$

Now you can repeatedly substitute to yield the infinite continued fraction.

Comment: The $\frac{2\alpha}{n}$ at the very end should be $\frac{2n}{\alpha}$.

Comment: thanks for pointing will fix when I get to a laptop. It is hard correct the LaTeX with my phone.