# What is integral of $e^{\cos^2x}dx$?

Tags: integration, special-functions, closed-form, error-function

I have tried to integrate  $e^{\cos ^2x}dx$   from $0 \to 1$ , Wolfram alpha showed me that is equal 2.11 as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+e%5E(cos%C2%B2x))dx,+x%3D0+to+1)
 but really i'm interested for it's  closed form using sompe special standard function  , my attempt is to use this basic
$$
\int \frac{e^u}{f'(x)}=\int\exp(f(x)) du. 
$$but it's seems don't works then any way to find it's integral  ?

Comment: I'd be shocked if it had any sort of reasonable/useful closed form.

Comment: [*(no result found in terms of standard mathematical functions)*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+e%5E(cos%C2%B2x))dx)

Comment: The Wolfram Dev Platform doesn't do any better. I doubt it has an elementary antiderivative.

Answer (score 5):

Such function does not have an elementary primitive by Risch algorithm, but on the other hand the Fourier series of $e^{\cos(2x)/2}$ is not a nightmare:
$$ e^{\cos(2x)/2} = I_0\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)+2\sum_{n\geq 1} I_{n}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\cos(2nx)\tag{1} $$
especially since the involved values of Bessel functions can be computed through [very simple continued fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871733/convergence-of-a-harmonic-continued-fraction). The RHS of $(1)$ can be termwise integrated over $(0,1)$ *et voilà*:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}e^{\cos^2(x)}\,dx = \sqrt{e}\,I_0\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)+\sqrt{e}\,\sum_{n\geq 1}I_{n}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\frac{\sin(2n)}{n}.\tag{2}$$

> I leave to you an interesting exercise - to compute the following limit:
>   $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\exp\left[\cos^2(nx)\right]\,dx.$$