# How do I show convergence of continued fraction?

Tags: real-analysis, continued-fractions

How can I show convergence of the following continued fraction?

$3+\cfrac{3}{3+\cfrac{3}{3+\cfrac{3}{3+\cfrac{3}{\cdots}}}}$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of the continued fraction \[1,1,1,...\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2987559/convergence-of-the-continued-fraction-1-1-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take the sequence $x_n=3+\frac{3}{x_{n-1}}$ and $x_1=3$
In case of convergence the limit of the sequence will verifie the following equation
$$L=3+\frac{3}{L}\implies L^2=3L+3\iff L=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{21}}{2}$$
And it must be $L=\frac{3+\sqrt{21}}{2}$, because the sequence is strictly positive. To prove the convergence we need monotony and boundedness. The monotony is easy to prove, is strictly increasing. Now we are gonna see the boundedness by some bound like for example $4$.

$x_1=3<4$ and $x_{k+1}<4\iff 3+3/x_k<4\iff 3<x_{k}$. That is true because $x_{n}$ is strictly increasing and $x_1=3$ So $x_n<4$,$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus is convergent and $$L=3+\frac{3}{3+\frac{3}{3+\frac{3}{3+\frac{3}{...}}}}=\frac{3+\sqrt{21}}{2}$$

Comment: Well, I gave a hint and you gave away the whole story.  :-(

Comment: Sorry, im pretty new here and sometimes i give too many details instead giving hints

Comment: No worry.   Just be careful of the moderators and other users who will down vote answers to questions that they deem are or poor quality.